# Custom Azure Dashboard Creation: Information about all Extensions and Part Types Supported

Tags: azure, dashboard, azure-resource-manager, azureportal

I am looking to create a custom dashboard for Azure portal using corresponding JSON templates. For the tiles within the dashboard, there are certain Extensions / part-types supported, for which there is very scarce documentation as far as I could find.

I need to find any further Information about any additional extensions / part-types supported in the dashboard, except the 4 part types already mentioned on the documentation page as shown below.

1. Extension/Microsoft_Azure_Monitoring/PartType/MetricsChartPart –
   Used to show monitoring metrics
2. Extension[azure]/HubsExtension/PartType/MarkdownPart – Used to show
   with text or images with basic formatting for lists, links,etc.
3. Extension[azure]/HubsExtension/PartType/VideoPart – Used to show
   videos from YouTube, Channel9, and any other type of video that
   works    in an html video tag.
4. Extension/Microsoft_Azure_Compute/PartType/VirtualMachinePart – Used
   to show the name and status of an Azure virtual machine.

I have extensively searched over Web, and came up with no further Info.

Kindly help me discover the Information.

Comment: You can find more details about the Extension in this document:https://github.com/Azure/portaldocs/tree/master/portal-sdk/generated    Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @WayneYang-MSFT. This is definitely very helpful. I wonder why I wasn't able to find this from web search earlier, even deep within ranks/pages.

Comment: Cheers! I'm glad to hear that it's helpful to you!  I will write it as answer and please mark it as an  answer so that we can help more more people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find more details about the Extension in [this document](https://github.com/Azure/portaldocs/tree/master/portal-sdk/generated).